# Where do files saved to "This PC" in Windows 11 actually go?

Tags: windows

I have not used Windows for many years and wonder now what this saving to "This PC" means.  When I created and saved a file in *Notepad* I was surprised to not see it in the *Documents* folder as shown in the sidebar.

[image: Saving a file to "This PC"]

```bash
C:\Users\StephenBoesch\Documents>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 9692-4C3C

 Directory of C:\Users\StephenBoesch\Documents

10/24/2022  12:39 PM    <DIR>          .
10/24/2022  08:55 PM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  396,585,881,600 bytes free
```

Here's another look at it: showing clearly in the `Documents` folder *in the gui* - but not from command line?

[image]

So then where is it actually going to ?

Comment: What if you right click one of the files and select Properties? Does it show the location?

Comment: BTW, the address bar in the Save As dialog does show _Documents_ ...

Comment: You can answer this question yourself by doing a right click in the free area below the "notes" file to open the context menu. Then open the "Properties" dialog which will show you the actual path.

Comment: @Berend and Robert: right clicking may seem obvious to you but I've been using macOS _Finder_ for many years and it does not work that way.  Pls make an answer about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Berend and @Robert mentioned right-clicking so see *properties*.  That does show the relevant info:

[image]

The strange thing is that the sidebar and the save file dialog both show `Documents` but the file is *actually* in a network shared drive `OneDrive`.  I wonder why is that..

Comment: OneDrive is _not_ a “network shared drive”. If we disregard voodoo like Files On Demand, it is a proper local folder that is synchronized to a cloud location. // You probably have OneDrive’s “Backup” feature enabled.

Comment: @DanielB  Do you understand/can you explain the disparity between what the `Save as` dialog is displaying (`Documents`) and the actual `OneDrive` from _properties_ (which I never selected for saving to..) ?  I'm a command line person and am presently bewildered as to where the files are actually living - and in particular how to access from the command line

Comment: There are multiple levels of indirection. The location of the _Documents_ (and _Pictures_, _Downloads_, _Movies_, …) folder can be changed. That’s what the OneDrive “Backup” feature does. // You already found out where the files are “physically” located.

Comment: Any idea what the _path_ is to them so I can access from cmdline? thx!

Comment: The path is exactly what's shown in the properties, i.e. `C:\Users\StephenBoesch\OneDrive - Blueprint Te...`. You can use this from the command line just like any other path